# Trackbar for picture morphology in opencv (python)

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-morphology

So my issue is that when I go to edit a photo I can't get the final settings from the trackbar to save and update the image.

I found code on github that I based my code on which is here:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/morphology.py

This is just implementation of trackbars. It doesn't even save between modes and the final image once you are out of the function definition does not change at all. So I have tried other ways. Here is one way that seemed promising:

```
def nothing(x):
pass

def isOrdered(img, cur_mode):
    str_mode = 'ellipse'
    cv2.namedWindow('edit')
    cv2.createTrackbar('op/size', 'edit', 11, 20, nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('iters', 'edit', 1, 10, nothing) 
    while(100):
        cv2.imshow('edit', img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
        sz = cv2.getTrackbarPos('op/size', 'edit')
        iters = cv2.getTrackbarPos('iters', 'edit')
        opers = cur_mode.split('/')
        if len(opers) > 1:
            sz = sz - 10
            op = opers[sz > 0]
            sz = abs(sz)
        else:
            op = opers[0]
        sz = sz*2+1

        str_name = 'MORPH_' + str_mode.upper()
        oper_name = 'MORPH_' + op.upper()
        st = cv2.getStructuringElement(getattr(cv2, str_name), (sz, sz))
        res = cv2.morphologyEx(img, getattr(cv2, oper_name), st, iterations=iters)

        draw_str(res, (10, 20), 'mode: ' + cur_mode)
        draw_str(res, (10, 40), 'operation: ' + oper_name)
        draw_str(res, (10, 60), 'structure: ' + str_name)
        draw_str(res, (10, 80), 'ksize: %d  iters: %d' % (sz, iters))
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return(sz, iters, op)


modes = ['erode/dilate', 'open/close', 'blackhat/tophat', 'gradient']
str_mode = 'ellipse'
for cur_mode in modes:
    sz, iters, op = isOrdered(im, cur_mode)
    str_name = 'MORPH_' + str_mode.upper()
    oper_name = 'MORPH_' + op.upper()
    st = cv2.getStructuringElement(getattr(cv2, str_name), (sz, sz))
    im = cv2.morphologyEx(im, getattr(cv2, oper_name), st, iterations=iters)
cv2.imshow('final', im)
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

with this way I can't get the picture to update while I am changing the track bar settings to be able to see what it's doing and the final image is black even though the intermediate images between modes isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep you original code, modify these lines.

```
    res = img.copy()
    while(100):
        #cv2.imshow("edit", img)
        cv2.imshow("edit", res)
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I was trying things for so long. I guess I still don't have the best understanding of how the code even executes which is probably why I couldn't trouble shoot the issue.